# Complete list of HTML5 features?

Tags: html, reference

There are some really good resources on HTML5 on the web such as [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) and http://slides.html5rocks.com and I have used many of the features mentioned in my own applications, so I'm not new to using HTML5.

But as I get further along in my study of HTML5 features, I keep uncovering more and more things that are classified under the heading of "HTML5". The most recent one I've heard about is the `keygen` tag which allows you to generate public private keypairs on the client side with ease. I'm pleased that this tag exists and also slightly disturbed that I had no idea about its existence till a few hours ago.

So is there a **complete** list of HTML5 features anywhere on the web? I am aware of the working draft at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ but I'm looking for something to the point and easy to understand without having to sift through reams of technical jargon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend the [specification for developers](http://developers.whatwg.org/).

Basically its what it says on the tin. But to clarify, this is from the press release at the time:

> It features find-as-you-type search,
>   offline access, beautiful typography,
>   technical references pulled inline,
>   and alternate styles for handheld
>   devices or low resolution displays.
>
> The aim? To produce a companion
>   specification for web developers to
>   use on a regular basis. All details
>   that are considered “for browser
>   vendors” are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

[W3C: HTML5 Differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)